# Closing a child application in a mother application

Tags: java, android, launch

I'm developing an Android application which had many child application.

I can launch child-app from my mother-app.
What I want to do, is to restart child-app when I launch them from mother-app, even if they were onPause().

I can't figure out how to do that, here is a sample code that I use to launch one of my child-app :

```
case R.id.tmt: 
    Intent i1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    PackageManager manager1 = getPackageManager();
    i1 = manager1.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myapp.tmt");
    i1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    bundle.putString("testName", "TMT");
    i1.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(i1);
    break;
```

Comment: You can send a broadcast with custom action. In the child application you need to implement [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and subscribe to this action. Once action has been received, you will call `finish` for the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read through LaunchMode and Intent Flags.

I guess for your requirement you can use the following if the child-app is in same task list,

***i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);***